# How to push a dynamic price to the datalayer?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-datalayer, data-layer

How can i send a dynamic price that should change to the datalayer? can't i simply send a variable like below example?

```
Var price; //this price will dynamically change based on the product value


  dataLayer.push({
  'event': 'gtm-event',
  'value': price
  });
```

Comment: you probably meant `price` instead of `'price'` (since it is a variable)?

Comment: Yes, so is that possible and correct? Or is it wrong?  cause on some sites it shows somethinking like obj.price or something else but not directly a variable.. :(

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about google-datalayer, but primitives in Javascript are passed by value, and objects by reference. So, consider

```
var price = 3;
var object_with_price = { price: 3 };

var data_with_price = { value: price };
var data_with_object = { value: object_with_price };
```

If you now change `price` to 4, `data_with_price.price` will still be 3 because the value had been passed.

But if you do `object_with_price.price = 4`, then `data_with_object.value.price` will also be 4.

If you change `object_with_price = { price: 5 }`, `data_with_object` will remain unchanged.